# A mobile app dictionary in android

Tags: android, dictionary, google-custom-search

I am trying to creating an android dictionary app. But instead of using a database of words I am trying to leverage on the Google Custom Search API. so when the user of my android native app enters a search word in english. My native android app goes to the web and uses the Google Custom Searhc Api to get the result. But I dont know how to communicate with Google Custom Search API from an android app. Please any link. I have been search but not gotten any use one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest 
I believe, this can be a good start for you. You need to use asynctasks to do your request, and the rest is up to your imagination and skills.